# how to set arguments dynamcally in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to pass arguments to the jquery $() dynamically.
Suppose this is my code

```
var myId = $(from).attr('id');
if (myId == 'ddlShiftDrop' || myId == 'ddlShiftDropGap') {
  var val = $('#'+myId+' option:selected').val();
  $('#ddlWorkTime').val(val);
}
```

Now i want to change the argument `$('#'+myId+' option:selected').val();` to `$('#'+myId+' option:selected' , window.parent.document).val();` as per some condition suppose `if(flag!=0)`.
I want best way to do this. So i have to write less code as possible, because there are number of places i have to do this.
THANKS

Comment: you mean something like `$('#'+myId+' option:selected', flag ? window.parent.document : document).val();`?

Comment: @Rhumborl Or even shorter $('#'+myId+' option:selected', flag && window.parent.document)